# Minimum number of splits in Matrix

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

There is a rectangular sheet which contains width x height square tiles. Sheet can be divided into two rectangular pieces by spliting from edges, horizontally or vertically.

For example, a 2x2 sheet can be divided into two 2x1 pieces, but it cannot be divided into two pieces, where one of them is 1x1. Sheet can be divided as many times as we want.

I want to create at least one piece which consists of exactly T tiles. How to find the minimal number of split operations necessary to reach this goal?

ex. if , width = 5 , height = 4 , T = 8,
   then 
      minimum number of splits = ?
There will be 2 pieces in 1st split: 2x4, 3x4.
 2x4 = 8 which is equal to T. Hence min. number of splits = 1.

I have brute force solution by which I can find the minimum number of splits required to get the T tiles in one sheet but I'm looking for optimized one. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: What are you doing currently?

Comment: @azurefrog- I'm just checking firstly row wise then column wise from i=0 to width/height of the matrix. if (i * m || i*n == T) then return i; My solution is not covering each cases.

Comment: if you think about it the worst case is always 2 splits

Comment: @radai - what if we are not getting into just two halves? I think in two halves we can only get something which is equal to n*n but in many cases T != nxn then we won't able to find into just two halves

Comment: @radai - May be in worst case there will be two splits always.

Comment: @radai - Is there any good approach to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let n and m be width and heigth of the board.

1. If T > n*m the desired split is obviously impossible.
2. If n or m divides T, then we can easily go with one split. Note that also only situations in which one split is enough are those when T is divisble by either n or m. Also, there is a special case - when T = n*m then we don't have to make *any* splits.
3. In the rest of the cases, as stated in 2., we have to make *at least* two splits. See that if T = a*b for some a <= n and b <= m then we can make one split to acquire a rectangle of size a x m, and then an other split to get a x b. So now we have to iterate through all possible pairs (a,b) such that T = a*b. If among them there is some pair that a rectangle a x b can fit in a board of size n x m, then we can respond that the answer is two splits. If no such pair is found, what can happen i.e. for T being a large prime number, then the splitting is impossible as in the case 1.

The complexity of the solution in some cases (namely 1. and 2.) is O(1), but in a general case (3.) it's O(sqrt T) as when we check all the pairs (a,b) that a*b = T then MIN(a,b) <= sqrt(T) - it's a common trick also used when searching for divisors of some number.